# jdbcTemplate.update(String sql) is behaving oddly

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Trying to understand jdbcTemplate.update(String sql) which is behaving oddly.

I have one method:

```
public int insertStartSyncDate() {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO iwpro_imp."+jobStatusTable+" (job_name,status,start_time,comment) VALUES ('sswltimport', 'running', NOW(), 'Just started.')";
    int resultsReturned = 0;
    try{
        resultsReturned = jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultsReturned;
}
```

My table structure is:

```
mysql> desc import_job_status;
+------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                               | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| job_id     | bigint(20) unsigned                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| job_name   | varchar(20)                        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| status     | enum('running','success','failed') | NO   | MUL | running           |                |
| start_time | timestamp                          | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| end_time   | timestamp                          | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| comment    | text                               | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the issue is:
After the execution of this method, data is not coming into DB table. I tried to debug and pointer is showing the value of resultsReturned as 1 which means query is executed. I don't understand now that what is wrong here.

[image: debug pointer showing resultsReturned value as 1]

How should I proceed now? I tried to run sql query manually and its fine when I run it manually but its not executing from "jdbcTemplate.update(sql)" method.

Comment: Did it commit into the database? Possibly the commit is not fired.

Comment: My auto commit is ON. its not off. Still I need to do it manually?

Comment: Nopes then it is the database which will do it for you.

Comment: Your @Transactional annotation for this method.. is it set as readOnly='true'?

Comment: yes you are right. Adding @Transactional worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nilesh and Maciej Kowalski for the hint.
My autocommit was off actually. Adding `@Transactional` annotation worked for me.

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager_iwpro_imp", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public int insertStartSyncDate() {
 // ......
}
```